# Primefaces change view since a Bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to know how I can change a view since a bean, and it is my code:

principal.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/resources/images/logoconsorcio.ico"/>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>
            <h:outputScript name="scripts/scripts.js" />
            <title>Consorcio JM</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <ui:include src="/pages/main/session_time_out.xhtml"/>
            <!-- Header Panel-->
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="40" resizable="true" closable="true" 
                          collapsible="true" collapseSize="20">
                <ui:include src="/pages/main/header.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <!-- Tree Panel-->
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="205"  collapsible="true" header="Menu">
                <ui:include src="/pages/main/page_menu.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <!-- Content Panel-->
            <p:layoutUnit id="idCenterLayout" position="center" >
                <p:outputPanel id="idCentroPagina">
                    <ui:include src="#{menuBean.paginaCentral}"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
```

in `#{menuBean.paginaCentral}` I put the path of the a view like `/pages/logistica/movimientos/orden_ingreso/orden_ingreso.xhtml`

orden_ingreso.xhtml

```
<ui:composition  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

<h:form id="idFormOrdenIngreso" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
    <p:growl id="idGrowlOI" showDetail="true" life="2500" for="keyOrdenIngreso" globalOnly="true"/>
    <p:panel header="Orden de Ingreso" styleClass="texto-panel"/>
    <ui:include src="/pages/logistica/movimientos/orden_ingreso/toolbar_orden_ingreso.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="#{ordenIngresoBean.pathBodyOrdenIngreso}"/>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

OrdenIngresoBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ordenIngresoBean")
@SessionScoped
public class OrdenIngresoBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String strBusiness = "OrdenIngresoBO";
private String pathBodyOrdenIngreso;
private OrdenIngresoBO ordenIngresoBO;
private OrdenIngresoUtil oiu;
private OrdenIngresoDTO oiVista;
private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
private final FacesContext facesContext;
private final Empresa empresa;
private final UsuarioLO usuario;


public OrdenIngresoBean () {
    facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    empresa = (Empresa)httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("empresaSession");
    usuario = (UsuarioLO)httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
    initBusiness();
    oiu = new OrdenIngresoUtil();
    oiu.setVista("LISTA");
    oiVista = new OrdenIngresoDTO();
    pathBodyOrdenIngreso = "/pages/logistica/movimientos/orden_ingreso/lista_orden_ingreso.xhtml";
}

private void initBusiness() {
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)facesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    ordenIngresoBO = (OrdenIngresoBO)ctx.getBean(strBusiness);
}

...

public void actualizarVista() {
    if(oiu.getIdEmisorComprobante().intValue() < 0){
        ProveedorBean proveedorBean = new ProveedorBean();
        proveedorBean.limpiarProveedorVista();
        proveedorBean.setPathBodyProveedor("/pages/logistica/proveedor/crear_proveedor.xhtml");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":idCentroPagina");
    }
}
```

in "actualizarVista" I want to change to other view, to `/pages/logistica/proveedor/crear_proveedor.xhtml` that is of another bean, but to do it I have to update the component "idCentroPagina" that is in `principal.xhtml`. I works with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":idCentroPagina")`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading colon. The leading colon is only usable when you are inside a naming container. So change

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":idCentroPagina")
```

into

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idCentroPagina")
```